# VBA PPT error while reading CR/LF character

Tags: vba, ascii, powerpoint, newline

I have encountered an odd problem while writing VBA macro for Ppt document.
In the code I would like to extract text in frames at the very top of each slide of my presentation.
The text is divided by newline character, so first I would like to search for newline character.
I am using `Instr` function to search for the position of a newline in a string.
The code is the following:

```
Sub SetTitle()
Dim sl As Slide
Dim sh As Shape
Dim trng As TextRange
Dim asptext() As Variant

For Each sl In ActivePresentation.Slides
    For Each sh In sl.Shapes
        If sh.Top = 5.403701 Then
            Set trng = sh.TextFrame.TextRange
            txt = trng.Text
            Debug.Print txt
            pos = InStr(1, Chr(13), txt)
            Debug.Print pos
            Debug.Print Asc(Mid(txt, 7, 1))
            If pos <> 0 Then
                Debug.Print pos
            End If
        End If
    Next sh
Next sl

End Sub
```

In **Immediate** window I am getting the following results : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig41i.png

The debugger gives an error:

```
Runtime error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument
```

for the line

```
Debug.Print Asc(Mid(txt, 7, 1))
```

So I suppose that there is a problem in recognizing this NL character.
Do you have any idea why it is like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error comes likely not from any NewLine character but from a string that is too short. `Mid(txt, 7, 1)` will return an empty string, and that is not a valid parameter for the `Asc`-function.

To check for Newline-characters, you can use the constants `vbCr` (same as `Chr(13)`) and `vbLf` (same as `Chr(10)`) and `vbCrLf`.

If you are unsure about the content of a string, you can use the following function:

```
Function DumpString(s As String) As String
    Const Separator = ", "
    
    ' Write all chars of String as ASCII-Value
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(s)

        Dim a As Long, c As String
        a = AscW(Mid(s, i, 1))
        
        If a = AscW(vbCr) Then
            c = "<CR>"
        ElseIf a = AscW(vbLf) Then
            c = "<LF>"
        ElseIf a = AscW(vbTab) Then
            c = "<TAB>"
        ElseIf a = 0 Then
            c = "<NUL>"
        Else
            c = Mid(s, i, 1)
        End If
        
        DumpString = DumpString & IIf(DumpString = "", "", Separator) & a & "(" & c & ")"
    Next i
End Function
```

Comment: PowerPoint may use unexpected characters for linebreaks; the biggie is that it uses Chr$(11) for linebreaks in most text and for both linebreaks and paragraph endings in Title placeholders. This page from the PPT FAQ I maintain describes the oddities:  Paragraph endings and line breaks
https://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00992_Paragraph_endings_and_line_breaks.htm